# Find the area enclosed by the following curve.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find the area enclosed by the curve:

$x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=a^{2/3}$

Also, is there a general method for finding the area enclosed by such symmetric equations?

Using a graphing program, I was able  to deduce that it has a diamond(actually an inside curved diamond shape). So, considering the symmetry of the equation, the area should be given by

$4\int_{x1}^{x2}y\ dx=4\int_{x1}^{x2}(a^{2/3}-x^{2/3})^{3/2}\ dx$

The above expression tells me that there has to a better method to do this. Because I am unable to integrate that expression.

Comment: See [astroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid) and [superellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse).

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** : $x=a\cos^3\theta$, $y=a\sin^3\theta$